# I have to load a .data, .item and other files with not valid extensions into a data frame in Python

Tags: python-3.x

They are tab separated lists. Being new to python, facing difficulty in loading it  using pd.read_csv('filename') command.

Comment: try `df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep='\t')`

Comment: What difficulty are you facing exactly?  An error message perhaps?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-070c23ddd578> in <module>
----> 1 movie=pd.read_text('u.data',sep='\t')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    212 
    213             return Panel
--> 214         raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
    215 
    216 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_text'

Comment: movie=pd.read_csv('u.data',sep='\t')

Comment: my code is: movie=pd.read_csv('u.data',sep='\t')